# how to join items of a list in a defined manner in Python

Tags: python, string, join

I have a list as below:

```
mylist = ['L11_1','E12_3','F7_3']
```

What I want to do is to create a string based on the items of mylist as below:

```
mystring = df['L11_1']+df['E12_3']+df['F7_3']
```

What I have tried is not straightforward:

```
for i in mylist:
    mystring='df['+"'"+i+"'"+']+'
    print(mystring,end='')
```

I tried to use the `join()` but was not sure how to define `df[]` with it. Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: what about `mystring = "".join(df[x] for x in mylist)`, I am assuming fd here is actually a dataframe or some sort of key based object and your trying to look up values based on the values in mylist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? You can define the df using [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```
mystring = "+".join([f"df['{x}']" for x in mylist])
print(mystring)
>>> df['L11_1']+df['E12_3']+df['F7_3']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['L11_1','E12_3','F7_3']
string = "+".join([f"df['{i}']" for i in mylist])
```

output:

```
"df['L11_1']+df['E12_3']+df['F7_3']"
```